# What's wrong with the following proof of the primitive element theorem?

Tags: number-theory

As most proofs of the primitive element theorem are rather tedious I wonder what's wrong with the following proof.

The proof is based on vector calculus: let $V$ be a vector space and $S$ be a finite set of proper linear subspaces then there is a $v \in V$ such that $v \notin \cup S$.
(this is easy to prove)

Now, let $E/K$ be a finite extension of a field $K$. Then an element $e \in E$ has a minimal polynomial of degree strictly less than $n$ iff $e$ belongs to a proper sub extension of $E$. But these sub extensions correspond one to one to the subgroups of the Galois group of the extension. Applying the statement above we obtain that there is an element with minimal polynomial of degree n.

Comment: If the field $K$ is finite, a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ of dimension $\geqslant 2$ over $K$ **is** the union of finitely many _proper_ subspaces.

Comment: That's one problem. Another is that you're assuming the extension is Galois.

Answer (score 2):

As the comments indicated, this is not a complete proof for various reasons. But it certainly can be turned into a proof for infinite fields and, in my opinion, it is the clearest proof.

Let $L/K$ be a finite separable extension, with $K$ infinite. Let $M$ be the Galois closure of $L/K$; let $G = Gal(M/K)$ and let $H$ be the subgroup fixing $L$. Then proper subfields of $L$ containing $K$ correspond to groups $\Gamma$ with $H \subsetneq \Gamma \subseteq G$. There are only finitely many such groups. Since $K$ is infinite, $L$ is not a union of finitely many proper $K$-subspaces. So there is some $\theta \in L$ which is not in any of these, and this $\theta$ is a primitive element.

Most books probably want to prove the primitive element theorem before setting up the Galois correspondence, so they can't do it this way. But there is no need to prove the primitive element theorem to prove any of the main results of Galois theory, and I find it clearest not to.

Comment: In the case $K$ is finite then it is known that the multiplicative group $L\setminus\{0\}$ is cyclic, thus generated by an element $\theta \in L$ so that every element of $L$ can be written as $a*\theta^i$ with $a \in K$ and $i \in \mathbb{Z}$.